# How to create a node based on views results

Tags: views

I'm looking for a way to accomplish the following:

Use views to select users that match a certain criteria.
Create a "campaign" targeted at only those users. The campaign should ideally have all users' names/ids attached to it.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need 2 relationships in Views. One that targets your field that points from user to the campaing. Second, with the author, based on the first relationship.
After, add as fields user names.
Not really sure about your structure so that was just a supposition.